# Kubernetes bash to POD after creation

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I tried to create the POD using command
 `kubectl  run  --generator=run-pod/v1 mypod--image=myimage:1 -it bash` and after successful pod creation it prompts for bash command in side container.

Is there anyway to achieve above command using YML file? I tried below YML but it does not go to bash directly after successful creation of POD. I had to manually write command `kubectl exec -it POD_NAME bash`. But want to avoid using exec command to bash my container. I want my YML to take me to my container after creation of POD. is there anyway to achieve this?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
  namespace: mynamespcae
  labels:
    app: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - bash
    name: mypod
    image: myimage:1
    stdin: true
    stdinOnce: true
    tty: true
```

Comment: There isn't, using only the Kubernetes YAML syntax.  What do you actually want the pod to do?  Why is having an interactive shell important?

Comment: @DavidMaze , I have multiple scripts files and each has to be run based on need. I was just looking alternates or I’ll use the command to create the pod which takes directly to interactive shell.

Comment: @user1591156 If it is not possible with YAML maybe you consider creating a shell script that creates the pod and then `exec` into it? I know this isn't the answer but it should be bearable to use.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a Job that will run the script, then exit?

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

As already mentioned by David, it is not possible to go to bash directly after a Pod is created by only using the YAML syntax. You have to use a proper `kubectl` command like `kubectl exec` in order to [Get a Shell to a Running Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/).

Answer (score -1):

The key you want to have the pod that will not exit.
Here is an example for you.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
  namespace: mynamespcae
  labels:
    app: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - bash
    - -c
    - yes > /dev/null
    name: mypod
    image: myimage:1
```

The command `yes` will continue to output the string `yes` until it is killed.
The part `> /dev/null` will make sure that you won't have a ton of garbage logs.
Then you can access your pod with these commands.

```
kubectl apply -f my-pod.yaml
kubectl exec -it mypod bash
```

Remember to remove the pod after you finish all the operations.